# Finite expansion of this function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I had this result as finite expansion of this function $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ to order n in neighborhood of 0:
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x^i.(i+1)) }+0(x^n)$$ (where x tends to 0)is it true? And if yes should i prove it by mathematical induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(answer edited following modifications of the question)*

Notice that your function is the derivative of $\frac1{1-x}$ which has a geometric series for its expansion at 0. You can expand your function by taking the term-by-term derivative of the geometric series.

If you do not want to use that argument, you can also obtain an expression for the $n$-th derivative of the function (inductively, using the form of the $(n-1)$-th derivative).

Comment: I edited it now is it true now?

Comment: No, it isn't I'm afraid. Notice that the 0-th term, which you took out of your infinite sum before, now fits in nicely - but with the wrong sign! The expansion could become correct if you leave out the alternating minus sign (or, alternatively, change the minus sign in your original function to a plus sign).

Comment: Yes you're right I'll correct it in the posted question

Comment: Ok but should i prove this by induction?

Comment: Technically *any* proof of a statement pertaining to a general natural number $n$ involves induction - only sometimes we do not mention it explicitly and it appears only in the form of a series of dots or something similar. In this case you could use induction to obtain the general form of the $n$-th derivative of the original function when you already know the $(n-1)$-th derivative.